# list-style-type string value works fine, even though it is not a valid value

Tags: css, web, value-of-css-property

I've been working on adding some lists to an existing project. One thing I needed was a '>' as the bullet point. Easy enough by using `.myselector:before` and setting the `content` to '>'.

Just out of curiosity, I tried to set this using `list-style-type` by setting it to '>`.

```
.myselector {
  list-style-type: '>';
}
```

I wasn't expecting it to work. VS Code even gives an error. But it works perfectly fine. The lists have a '>' instead of the default circle and there aren't any browser errors. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type it si possible to use string as value of `list-style-type`. The problem is that, not every browser supports it - for example Safari or Edge. For now I recommend using `::before` as best solution.

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I didn't see that section of the docs. This explains why it isn't commonly recommended.